# What characteristics do living organisms (like humans or plants) have that viruses don't?

Tags: virology

I am not too sure if viruses are considered living organisms.

I learned that living organism:

-Change their size
-Reproduce
-Heal themselves
-Need energy (by eating)
-React to the environment
-Have a lifespan
-Made of at least 1 cell (some exceptions)

Which features that are listed are not in viruses?

If I need to be more clear, please tell me as I'm not very good at explaining.

Comment: @DeNovo Hm the answers to those questions are very helpful. I just would like to know which of the characteristics I've posted are the same characteristics in viruses.

Answer (score -1):

Linving organisms have intricate metabolic pathways that viruses donot have viruses stay in equilibrium till they infect host meaning that they they donot exachange matter and energy with surronding when they are outside the body but is a property shown by humans and living organisms.

Comment: Hi Udaya, welcome to BIO.SE! In general, we ask/require that answers provide support (typically through reputable sources + images) for their claims. In this way, we can better ensure more accurate responses. Please update your answer with more details and some reputable sources to avoid having your question closed. Thanks!